# Add task to asyncio loop running in separate thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I'm trying to run an asyncio loop in a separate thread from my main thread. While the thread and loop are running, I would like to add new tasks to it. I have the following code:

```py
class Craft:
    # [...]

    async def exec_subscription(self, session, subscription: str, variable_values: dict, callback: Callable) -> None:
        """Execute a subscription on the GraphQL API."""
        async for response in session.subscribe(gql(subscription), variable_values=variable_values):
            callback(response)

    def subscribe_job(self, job_id: int, callback: Callable) -> Union[bool, None]:
        """Subscribe to a job, receive the job information every time it is updated and pass it to a callback function."""

        async def _schedule_subscription_task(subscribe_job: str, variable_values: dict, callback: Callable) -> None:
            """Schedule subscription task in asyncio loop using existing websocket connection."""
            async with self._ws_client as session:
                task = asyncio.create_task(self.exec_subscription(session, subscribe_job, variable_values, callback))
                await asyncio.gather(task)
 
        def _run_subscription_loop(subscribe_job: str, variable_values: dict, callback: Callable) -> None:
            """Run asyncio loop."""
            asyncio.run(_schedule_subscription_task(subscribe_job, variable_values, callback))

        # Build GraphQL subscription
        subscribe_job = """
            subscription jobSubscription($jobId: Int!) {
                jobSubscriptionById(id: $jobId) {
                    job {...}
                }
            }
        """

        # Build variables dictionary
        variable_values = {
            'jobId': job_id
        }

        # Check if subscription thread is running
        thread_name = 'CraftSubscriptionThread'
        for thread in threading.enumerate():
            # If thread is found, add subscription to existing asyncio loop
            if thread.name == thread_name:
                # Add task to asyncio loop
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(_schedule_subscription_task(subscribe_job, variable_values, callback), loop)
                return True

        # Else create new event loop and new thread
        thread = threading.Thread(name=thread_name, daemon=True, target=_run_subscription_loop, args=(subscribe_job, variable_values, callback))
        thread.start()

        return True
```

In a Python terminal, I run the main method `subscribe_job` with the following callback function:

```py
from craft import Craft

global updated_job
updated_job = "0"

def print_job(job):
    global updated_job
    updated_job = job
    print(updated_job)

craft.subscribe_job(1561, print_job)
```

This works well and when the subscription receives a message, it prints the job in the terminal:

```
>>> {'jobSubscriptionById': {'job': {'id': 1561, 'spaceId': 1, 'applicationId': 47, 'configurationId': 139, 'title': 'Job 1631357928', 'description': None, 'status': 'failed', 'step': 1, 'progress': '1.00'}}}
```

However, when I trigger another subscription to add a new task to my loop, it seems nothing happens. I simply trigger a new subscription for a different job as below, it supposedly call `run_coroutine_threadsafe`:

```py
craft.subscribe_job(1561, print_job)
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem I see with your code is the line `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()`. This method gets the currently running event loop **in the current thread** and if one does not exist, it creates one. The problem is the second time you call `subscribe` you're calling it from your main thread and you've only ever started an event loop in your `CraftSubscriptionThread` thread, therefore `get_event_loop` creates a new event loop which isn't even running (print `loop.is_running()` after you call `get_event_loop()` - it will return `False`), explaining why nothing happens.

Also note that `asyncio.run` creates a new event loop every time you call it, which based on your description does not sound like what you want. I would avoid looping through to see if the `CraftSubscriptionThread` thread is running and trying to get the event loop. Instead, create a thread with one explicit event loop and then start it with `run_forever`. Then, when you submit to your threaded event loop you can call `run_coroutine_threadsafe` as you were before. Here is a simplified version of your code that should illustrate how to solve this problem:

```
class ThreadedEventLoop(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.daemon = True

    async def exec_subscription(self, callback: Callable) -> None:
        while True: #Simulate the callback firing every two seconds.
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
            callback('hello!')

    async def schedule_subscription_task(self, callback):
        await self.exec_subscription(callback)

    def submit(self, callback):
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.schedule_subscription_task(callback), self._loop)

    def run(self) -> None:
        self._loop.run_forever()


def print_job(job):
    print('job1: updated_job')


def print_job2(job):
    print('job2: updated_job')


threaded_loop = ThreadedEventLoop()
threaded_loop.start()
threaded_loop.submit(print_job)
threaded_loop.submit(print_job2)
threaded_loop.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the code you provided, `subscribe_job()` is running in the main thread.  Therefore, when you execute this line:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

the loop you are retrieving is the event loop in the main thread.  That's not what you want; you want the loop in the secondary thread.  Since you say that nothing happens when you call `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` in the next line, I will venture to guess that your program has not actually started the event loop in the main thread.  Otherwise, you would see the function actually run - but it would be executing in the main thread.

It takes a bit of work to fix this.  You need to retrieve the secondary thread's event loop and store it in a variable.  I'm guessing a little bit about how the rest of your program is written, but one approach would be to create a member variable in the class's constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.secondary_loop = None
```

Now in your nested function `async def schedule_subscription_task(...)` add this line:

```
async def schedule_subscription_task(...):
    self.secondary_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
```

Back in the main part of `subscribe_job`, change your call to `run_coroutine_threadsafe` to this:

```
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(..., self.secondary_loop)
```

Admittedly there is a race condition here.  The variable self.secondary_loop doesn't get set immediately upon launching the secondary thread.  If you call `subscribe_job` twice in rapid succession, that variable may still be None even though you have actually started the secondary thread.  You might need to add a small time delay after thread creation, which will only run once and shouldn't affect noticeably the performance of the program.